# How to solve bleaching Krusader?

Tags: 12.04, krusader

I frequently use Krusader (Version 2.4.0-beta1 "Migration") file manager. It seems I have done something (mouse drag?) that resulted in a completely empty (white) Krusader window except for its title bar. Restarting the PC does not solve it. Even reinstalling Krusader from the Ubuntu Software Center did not solve it.

I have a relatively fresh clonezilla copy of the Ubuntu system partition; do I have to use it for the purpose? What I must not do with the Krusader to avoid such crashes? May it be caused by a graphics driver?

My [system](http://tpeceny.nazory.cz/soubory/Krusader/Screenshot%20from%202014-10-31%2011_01_51.png) and the [display](http://tpeceny.nazory.cz/soubory/Krusader/Screenshot%20from%202014-10-31%2011_02_37.png) after launching the Krusader.

After entering the password, the KDE Wallet Window disappears. After restarting the PC (after an Update Manager action) only the red icon on the right above the display whitens. Krusader still behaves as described.

The behavior is a matter of the system state of the concerned PC (at the following pictures, running debugger of an other Krusader version at both the PCs is shown.): I have two identical PCs. [One of them](http://tpeceny.nazory.cz/soubory/Krusader/Screenshot%20from%202014-11-01%2008_02_54.png) bleaches Krusader.

```
$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82865G/PE/P DRAM Controller/Host-Hub Interface (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company d330 uT
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at f8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company D530 sff(dc578av)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at fc400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    I/O ports at 14e0 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: intelfb, i915

00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 82865G/PE/P Processor to I/O Memory Interface (rev 02)
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at fecf0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
```

[The other](http://tpeceny.nazory.cz/soubory/Krusader/Screenshot%20from%202014-11-01%2008_02_17.png) does not bleach Krusader, now.

```
$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82865G/PE/P DRAM Controller/Host-Hub Interface (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company d330 uT
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at f8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company D530 sff(dc578av)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at fc400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    I/O ports at 24e0 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: intelfb, i915

00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 82865G/PE/P Processor to I/O Memory Interface (rev 02)
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at 40100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
```

I suspect that the graphics driver is not fully compatible with my 
system, because both the computers have recently started to show a oscillating picture when waking up from the "suspend" status in Ubuntu (not in Windows).

I tried to install a newer Intel 82865G graphics driver. I have not found it prepared for Ubuntu 12.04.

I upgraded the system of the PC with bleached Krusader to Ubuntu 14.04 and used the `intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.6-0intel1_i386.deb` from Intel's site; it installed a further repository. I understand that it should yield new drivers. I have updated the system with Software Updater. But Krusader remains bleached also after PC restart.

I also tried to use the disk from the other PC. In the Ubuntu 12.04 the Krusader works OK, so the graphics hardware has not failed.

On an older PC of a similar sort, in Ubuntu 12.04 the Krusader works OK:

```
$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82815 815 Chipset Host Bridge and Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82815 Chipset Graphics Controller (CGC) (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Compaq Computer Corporation Device 001a
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
    Memory at 44000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
    Memory at 40500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=64
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: 40000000-404fffff
    Kernel modules: shpchp
```

This older PC wakes up OK from the "suspend" status, as did both the other PCs some time ago.

Now, I see Krusader bleached on the older PC, too: I caused it by trying to look at the content of a directory while Krusader copied several GiBs from another PC.
The Krusader window remained white after clicking **Pause**, too. But another instance of Krusader worked OK at the same time. After restarting the older PC the Krusader remains bleached and another Krusader instance called from an other Terminal is bleached, too.

First, I suspected my old hardware and its drivers. As a reply to a comment: Installing pciutils in the Ubuntu 14.04 did not succeed. From the `lshw` listing, a part about graphics is

```
*-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:16 memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:fc400000-fc47ffff ioport:14e0(size=8)
    *-generic UNCLAIMED
         description: System peripheral
         product: 82865G/PE/P Processor to I/O Memory Interface
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 6
         bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
         version: 02
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:fecf0000-fecf0fff
```

To Wilf's idea of Terminal warnings: The bleached Krusader in Ubuntu 14.04 tells

```
$ krusader
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath)
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QDBusObjectPath)
krusader(5824)/kdecore (KLibrary) findLibraryInternal: plugins should not have a 'lib' prefix: "libkonsolepart.so"
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable") 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block") 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block") 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/SanDisk_SDDR_113_6333011111B1" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive") 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/SanDisk_SDDR_113_6333011111B1" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive") 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable") 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem", "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition")
```

The bleached Krusader in Ubuntu 12.04 of the old PC tells

```
$ krusader
krusader(2584)/kdecore (KLibrary) findLibraryInternal: plugins should not have a 'lib' prefix: "libkonsolepart.so"
```

I'm looking for Krusader configuration file(s). Are they in the `~/.kde` directory? Which file is it particularly? I'd like to delete the file only before reinstalling Krusader. I am afraid of deleting whole the directory because I have installed other KDE programs. (The KDiff3 is not bleached in the Ubuntu 14.04 of the first PC nor in the Ubuntu 12.04 of the older PC.)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the issue? Also, what desktop environment (GNOME, Unity, KDE, etc) are you using?

Comment: @Wilf, I have edited the question to add the information. Thanks!

Comment: @Wilf, I have edited the question again with pictures from the Qt debugger. I am prepared to co-work with Krusader developers; can you give me a contact? I hesitate to use a general bug announcing procedure, because it may be a matter of my particular old PCs. Thanks!

Comment: Does the bleaching occur every time you start Krusader? You could try installing and/or using the KDE dekstop, as Krusader may require that to work properly. You can get the contact details from [the Krusader site](http://www.krusader.org/documentation/index.html), and you can also try the [Krusader forum](http://forum.krusader.org/)

Comment: Yes, now, the bleaching occurs every time I start Krusader at the first PC. I am glad that I became accustomed to use the system described. Would the KDE desktop installation bring a great change of controlling?

Comment: A bit - you can customize it fairly easily though. You can chooe which Desktop to use at the login screen. However, just installing KDE it may be enough for it to work, as Krusader may be missing something it needs *(if you do install it, choose `lightdm`/`gdm` if it prompts, `kdm` probably does not work well with Unity)*. Since graphics may be relevant, could you please add the relevant output (referring to graphics stuff) of `lspci -v` from both machines? And do you have any idea of what could of caused the problem

Comment: @Wilf, I have edited the question again to add the information. I was looking for the graphics drivers at the Intel web site, but I'm not sure how to install a newer driver. Moreover, the computers (originally Hewlett Packard Compaq D530 SFF) were not designed for Linux. All my home network is based on PCs of that sort. Up to now, all necessary for me worked well and I do not want to risk much with installing, though I backup the system partition by the Clonezilla program.

Comment: @Wilf, I have edited the question once more with an attempt to update the graphics driver. Can you advise me with it? I worry about what I must not do with Krusader to avoid such an accident. I thank you for your bounty.

Comment: You could see if any messages appear in terminal when running `krusader`). so krusader bleached even after the update to 14.04? I think you can install lspci with `sudo apt-get install pciutils` - you can also use `lshw` to list hardware info.

Comment: @Wilf, yes, krusader is bleached also after the upgrade to 14.04; I have not installed it again after the upgrade. I have edited the question once more to add the information. Now, it appears to me that the bleaching is a krusader bug, not a result of my old hardware. I'd like if somebody with a modern PC reproduced the attempt to open a directory by Krusader while it copies, but it is too much work, because I do not yet know how to heal Krusader from the bleached status. Do you think it is better to try yet the KDE desktop, or right to announce it as a bug? Thanks!

Comment: I would try the KDE desktop, and then [report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). Note there are a few [alternatives](http://168hours.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/10-total-commander-alternatives-for-linux/) to Krusader.

Comment: @TomasPeceny Has Krusader worked in the past, or has this problem just started?

Comment: @Johnn : Krusader has worked all the time up to now at the PCs where it did not crash. Up to now, I cannot heal its bleaching by an other way then by restoring a system partition from a clonezilla backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that on my machine, hitting Ctrl+F (toggle full screen terminal) in krusader leads to that same completely white krusader window - and it stays that way until you hit Ctrl+F again.

If it happens again: give that a try.

Comment: I see the bug also with my Dell Optiplex 7010;  it is the first crash, I've been using it for 8 months.

Answer (score 1):

For one of my PCs, that now uses the Nvidia graphics card, the bleached Krusader starts to operate normally after setting all the the Krusader user settings to defaults.

A good idea is to note everything that has been set. Then run the Krusader Konfigurator and for all items (**Panel**, **General**, ...) click the **Default** button and confirm the action.

(At the other PC I have not seen the bleached state since I have guessed the solution, but I believe that the treatment also helps. By many attempts, I found out that the bug has something to do with settings. The whole problem may be caused by my using old CPUs not certified for Ubuntu.)

For a yet older Pentium III HP Compaq using its integrated graphics only, the treatment helps, too.