# How to reset Krusader configuration to defaults / remove corrupted config file?

Tags: kde, configuration, plugins, krusader, kde-apps

I have the problem described here: [How to solve bleaching Krusader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543862/how-to-solve-bleaching-krusader) and I want to reset Krusader configuration to fresh-install-like one.
(unfortunately opening configuration and applying defaults does not help)

1. How can I completely reset Krusader configuration to fresh-install-like one (preferably) or
2. Remove Krusader config file (what's the name and where's it located?)

I tried to remove configuration files as described here: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-utils/krusader/config_files.html but:

```
$ qtpaths --paths GenericDataLocation
qtpaths: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

And no such files exist:

```
~/.config/krusaderrc
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/krusader/krusaderui.rc
```

I do not believe that global config is screwed as this user has no access there nor this user is in sudoers list.

One important thing to mention is that when I start Krusader from terminal the following error message is printed:

```
$ krusader
krusader(6646)/kdecore (KLibrary) findLibraryInternal: plugins should not have a 'lib' prefix: "libkonsolepart.so"
```

So it looks like there is some package conflict - before I had installed some other utilities krusader had worked as expected. See the exact description in linked question (bleaching Krusader).

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get purge krusader`, followed by `sudo apt-get install krusader`? Also this link might be helpful: [docs.kde.org](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-utils/krusader/config_files.html)

Comment: Thanks @jarleih for valuable suggestion. I've updated the question based on your input

Answer (score 3):

```
apt-get purge krusader
```

and removing `~/.config/krusaderrc` for each user

and then reinstalling

```
apt-get install krusader
```

reverts Krusader to "factory default", showing the initial config dialog where you can set all the paths to the tools that Krusaders uses. That should erase all the config that exists.

Comment: OP says `~/.config/krusaderrc` doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm taking  from my own experience, I just tried this out and Krusader does create this file and reacts as described to it being erased. He might have had a global config hanging around and wiped that with apt-get purge already.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to update the locate database as root:

`sudo updatedb`

Then find the configuration file:

`sudo locate krusaderrc`

In mycase there were 3 files:

```
/home/mysuer/.config/krusaderrc
/home/mysuer/.config/krusaderrc.lock
/root/.config/krusaderrc
```